# Where is python freeze utility

Tags: python, macos, freeze

I just installed python 2.6 on my mac, mainly because I couldn't find freeze in my 2.5 distribution. I am wondering where freeze is. Is it even installed at all in the mac distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's installed as part of the Mac distribution; you can find it online [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Tools/freeze/), or perhaps more conveniently download and unpack the sources separately e.g. from [here](http://python.org/ftp/python/2.6.5/Python-2.6.5.tar.bz2) (then you'll find the `freeze` directory right under the `Tools` directory in the unpacked tree of sources).

Comment: The Python project has moved from Subversion to Mercurial. The current link to freeze ist: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Tools/freeze

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the built-in freeze, you might want to look at some of the third-party variations on the same idea.  I keep [this list](http://www.freehackers.org/Packaging%5Fa%5Fpython%5Fprogram) bookmarked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just targetting *nix systems, I've found [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/497000-build-a-compressed-self-extracting-executable-scri/) to be pretty helpful on occassion.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this project, however, I believe that this website is what you are after: http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html